# ValueError when making predictions with LinearRegression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have started learning ML.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Import the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values


# Split the data set into Training Set and Test Set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test =\
   train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=1/3, random_state=0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Simple Linear Regression to Training Set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train , Y_train)


# Predicting the Test set Results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a
>   minimum of 1 is required.

for the last line. How to resolve this??

Comment: it is impossible to read your question. Edit it to add missing newlines and indent the code with 4 spaces or select all the code then use button `{}`

Comment: As the error message says: the `X_test` array you are passing contains zero samples (rows). Check the output of 'train_test_split` and verify that you are reading in your data correctly.